# horizontal slide between pages

Tags: jquery, css

Could somebody help me to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar which appears when sliding between the content of the main div? I'm happy with the effect but I can't get rid of the horizontal scrollbar :(

Here's a jsfiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/62Ybt/1/

```
.content{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:50px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 1s;
  -o-transition: margin-left 1s;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  overflow-x:hidden;} // this part doesn't seem to be working
```

Comment: You should give `overflow: hidden` to the parent container in which the labels are being shown. In the jsfiddle, the parent container is `body`. So give `body{overflow: hidden}`.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrollbar in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your overflow CSS setting doesn't work, because the scrollbar/overflow isn't part of that particular container.

Try adding the `overflow-x: hidden` to the parent container, for example the body.

I updated your fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/62Ybt/6/

On an unrelated note: is it intended that you can click again on the currently active section name, and then none is shown at all?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the `overflow-x: hidden` to the `.wrapper` div and it seems to have done the trick.
And I'll fix the clicking on the currently active section. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. But remember to mark answers as accepted when they fix your problem, looking at your question history you don't seem to have done that yet ;)

Comment: @mick_smick: In your example, you had no div with a class wrapper.

Comment: @TLindig: My bad. I've updated the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/michal_s/62Ybt/13/

Answer (score -1):

add `overflow:hidden` to body. see example

update link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/62Ybt/9/

Comment: This does **not** fix it. Let me say that again, it does but you didnt  put it in your demo but putting overflow on your body is not good.

Comment: it fix the example. Why you think, that is it not good solution?

Comment: @Ruddy: Could you please tell us, what your are changed?

Comment: You get the overflow and didnt say what way to do it. So it has done everything. I have placed a `div` that has a height of `1000px`. Its being cut off by the bottom now because of the overflow on the body.

Comment: @Ruddy: That is a problem of the markup of this given example. Don't down vote my answer for that or do it with all other too.

Comment: Your answer should be a valid solution for this problem. It does solve the problem but causes others. The idea for this site is help people with there code in the best way possible. Not solve a problem knowing we just caused more problems.